# Symfony2 Process component - unable to create pipe and launch a new process

Tags: php, symfony, process, symfony-process

I'm using the Symfony2 Process component to manually manage a pool of processes.

In the example below I restart 2 simple processes every 2 seconds and monitor what happens. The application breaks after restarting these processes a few hundred times.

Execution is stopped and I get the following PHP warning:

```
proc_open(): unable to create pipe Too many open files
```

and then the following exception is thrown by the Symfony Process component:

```
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]  
Unable to launch a new process.
```

I've manually monitored the total number of open processes and it never goes up the expected limit.

The below simplified snippet is part of a Symfony2 command and is being runned from the CLI (e.g. app/console hamster:run):

```
    $processes[] = new Process("ls > /dev/null", null, null, null, 2);
    $processes[] = new Process("date > /dev/null", null, null, null, 2);

    while (count($processes) > 0) {
        foreach ($processes as $i => $process) {
            if (!$process->isStarted()) {
                $process->start();

                continue;
            }

            try {
                $process->checkTimeout();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                // Don't stop main thread execution
            }

            if (!$process->isRunning()) {
                // All processes are timed out after 2 seconds and restarted afterwards
                $process->restart();
            }
        }

        usleep($sleep * 1000000);
    }
```

This application is being run on a MAC server running OS X 10.8.4.

I would appreciate any hints on how to pursue the root of this issue.

**Update #1:** I've simplified my function to work with basic commands like `ls` and `date` for faster testing. It still looks like the Process command fails after starting and stopping about 1000-1500 processes.

I suspected that `proc_close()` was not being called correctly for each process, but further investigation revealed that's not the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file handles are not being garbage collected, so they eventually fill up (os limit or php limit, not sure), but you can fix it by adding an [explicit garbage collection call](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php):

```
gc_collect_cycles();
usleep($sleep * 1000000);
```

Also, be forwarned that garbage collection doesn't work very well inside a `foreach` loop because of the way that php maps the temporary `$foo as $bar => $var` array variables into memory. If you need it in that part of the code you could switch it to something like this instead, which I *think* should allow for garbage collection inside the `for` loop:

```
$processes[] = new Process("ls > /dev/null", null, null, null, 2);
$processes[] = new Process("date > /dev/null", null, null, null, 2);

$sleep = 0;

do {
    $count = count($processes);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if (!$processes[$i]->isStarted()) {
            $processes[$i]->start();

            continue;
        }

        try {
            $processes[$i]->checkTimeout();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Don't stop main thread execution
        }

        if (!$processes[$i]->isRunning()) {
            // All processes are timed out after 2 seconds and restarted afterwards
            $processes[$i]->restart();
        }

        gc_collect_cycles();
    }

    usleep($sleep * 1000000);
} while ($count > 0);
```

Comment: Good point. I didn't consider the necessity of manually calling the garbage collector. Performing some additional benchmarks (restarted the processes 100,000+ times) with the `gc_collect_cycles()` confirmed your solution. Thanks!

Comment: a better way would be to `->stop(0)` the process instance when done, this would effectively close the open file descriptors without having to rely on `__destruct` being called by the garbage collector.

Comment: You saved my life with this! Is the sleep necessary?